Error occurred while building ci using yarn berry and github action
Error: YAMLException: end of the stream or a document separator is expected at line 3, column 11:
    nodeLinker: pnp
              ^
    at generateError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:126542:10)
    at throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:126548:9)
    at readDocument (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:127914:5)
    at loadDocuments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:127950:5)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:127971:19)
    at safeLoad (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:127993:10)
    at parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:64242:18)
    at module.exports.exports.default (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:63793:96)
    at loadRcFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:57527:58)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:57501:14

An error like the above occurred.
.yarnrc.yml

nodeLinker: pnp

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.4.1.cjs


And this is my .yarnrc.yml file. Is there a mistake?
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, develop]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x, 20.x]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Enable Corepack
        run: corepack enable

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Run tests
        run: yarn test --passWithNoTests

      - name: Build project
        run: yarn build

And this may be helpful, but this is the project's workflows yml file
I was building a CI for a project using yarn berry and github actions, but I got an error like a syntax error in the yarnrc.yml file. There doesn't seem to be any syntax error, so what's the problem?

Is .yarnrc.yml part of your YAML file? It apparently is. Just tried to format it online here (https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter/6dcf57) and it shows the same error i.e. "end of the stream or a document separator is expected". Removing the first line (.yarnrc.yml) makes it valid YAML.

Thank you very much. It was a very simple problem :)
